# Display HTML from Static Resource in VF Page

Tags: visualforce, staticresource

I have a HTML file in Static Resource, which I need to display in one of the sections as an overlay in Visualforce page.

How can this be achieved? I tried including directly, did not seem to work

Answer (score 0):

Got the fix, using jQuery.

```
//Get the URL of the HTML Page
var pageURL = "{!$Resource.ResourceName}/html/PageName.html";

//Load the HTML Content to the element(based on ID or Class)
$('.target-element').load(pageURL);
```